# Bootstrap unwanted white space while display is mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap with my website and came across some odd white space that I can't seem to get rid of. If anyone has encountered this before it is only happening on a few devices Iphone6, Galaxy s4, Galaxy Note 3.

There is `margin: 0; padding: 0;`, on the `<li>`.

```
 <ul class="nav nav-justified">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li id="large"><a href="#" id="large" class="play">PLAY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Promotions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Heres an image of what I mean about the white space.

[image]

This is what is looks like on most devices:

[image]

Comment: need more info (specifically css), until i see that, have you tried setting `border:none`?

Comment: You can view the site here and check out the css if you'd like and mess around with the inspector/firebug, http://c2-tech.com it's still in production so don't mind any mistakes or messy code. Border none is not solving the problem as well

Answer (score 1):

In your intial question, that's just a screenshot from developer view yes?

I believe it's just a rendering fault when you first switch into mobile device mode.

I can replicate it [here](http://puu.sh/iD8AW.png), then notice what happens when i switch to the iphone 6 preview and then back to the S4 [(link)](http://puu.sh/iD8EB.png), the issue resolves itself. I have done absolutely nothing to the css, merely refreshed the view, thus im thinking it must be a dev tools issue.

If you wish to be 100% certain you can run something like browsersync through NodeJS locally and then connect up an actual S4 or iphone and check that. Or something like [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/) which uses VM's of actual OS's to ensure the most accurate results possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `border-top: value;` and `border-bottom: value` in the `li` tags to get this result.

This is what I did , I inspected the page , and added the border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; border-top: 1px solid #fff; to the li elements. It was okay and promising toward the view you wanted . So you have to add this kind of style in ul li tags of that position .

Comment: I tried this several different ways, no border, border same color as the background, no border bottom, etc. Always the white space comes back for some reason

Comment: can you give us ... stylesheet?

Comment: check comment above to Matthew Rath

Comment: This is what I did , I inspected the page , and added the                               `border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
border-top: 1px solid #fff;`   to the `li` elements. It was okay and promising toward the view you wanted . So you have to add this kind of style in `ul li` tags of that position .

Comment: Im trying to get rid of the white space so it looks like the second picture.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Remove `margin-bottom: 0;`.in your custom.css

```
 .nav-justified > li > a {
   padding-top: 15px;
   padding-bottom: 15px;
  /* margin-bottom: 0;*/
   font-weight: bold;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #14222d; /* Old browsers */
   }
```